# slow mysql queries - php javascript ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session-variables

I am using AJAX to post (method: post) the details of a form (has 35 fields), to a PHP script that does an INSERT INTO and returns "Data Saved," to the javascript (not using jquery). The javascript pops up an alert() to display the message.

The AJAX part:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                //alert("object found");
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
            {
              document.getElementById("loader_datasave").style.display='none';
                alert(xhttp.responseText);
                show_modal_writedb(false);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "writetodb.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(str);
```

Server: The server is installed on a laptop connected to the LAN. I am using USBWebserver as the server software on Windows 8.

Client: There are about 7 users using the form. It runs smoothly mostly and takes about half a seconds before the message pops up, however sometimes the form takes more than a minute to return the message. It would not even load other pages saved on the server while the user is waiting for the message from the PHP script. The delay affects everyone using the form.

I thought that, the session locking by PHP, could be the reason, so I used session_write_close(), right after a session_start(), since I don't write anything to the session variables.

I am not sure what is taking time. I have tried Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge, and Firefox, however the results are the same.

Should I use other servers like Wamp, or Xampp? All your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A profiler like xhprof or xdebug's call trace output might give some clues.

Comment: Thank you, jedifans. Appreciate your help.